# need to override function in jquery.ui.datepicker.js

Tags: jquery

In this location in wordpress

**/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui**

there is a file jquery.ui.datepicker.js

I need to override this bit of code

```
    noWeekends: function(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [(day > 0 && day < 6), ''];
    },
```

to make it only show wednesdays (day > 2 && day < 4). Obviously I don't want to do it in the file itself as it will get overridden. I tried a few things I've found online in the header, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Looking for either a code for the header, or the function file.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but this should work and don't forget to replace the jQuery selector with your own:

```
$(function() {
 if(typeof jQuery.datepicker === 'function'){
    $( ".your_date_picker_field_selector" ).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (t) {
            var e = t.getDay();
            return [e == 3, ""]
        }
    });
  }
});
```

**Updated:** Since, you are using contact form 7 datepicker addon, use filter to customize the meeting date field js.

```
add_filter( 'cf7dp_datepicker_javascript', 'custom_date_picker_js', 10, 2 );

function custom_date_picker_js( $out, $field ) {
       // Target only the meeting date field.
       if ( $field->type != 'datepicker' || $field->input_name != 'date-553' ) {
            return $out;
    }

    $out .= ".datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', function (t) {
        var e = t.getDay();
        return [e == 3, \"\"]
    })";
    $out .= ".datepicker('refresh');";

    return $out;
}
```

Comment: I did remember to change the selector, but I am getting a "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
$( "#ui-datepicker-div" ).datepicker({"

Comment: Enqueue the datepicker js wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');

Comment: I've enqueued the script in my functions file, but still get the same error. I don't know if a link to my site would be helpful or not: http://www.bnidynamo.com/guest-registration/

Comment: Check the updated answer. It should work.